# How to access contents of an uploaded JSON file in a Play application

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, httprequest

I want to upload the contents of a JSON file to my DB by using a Play application/api.

My HTML view looks like this:

```
@main("Welcome to Play") {
    <h1> Upload a JSON file </h1>
    @helper.form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "text/json") {
        <input type="file" name="jsonFile">
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </p>
    }
}
```

[upload view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlNni.png)

I defined my upload method in the controller. Ideally I want to upload the content to Cassandra but first I have to access the content of the file itself.

```
def upload = Action { request =>
  val data = request.body.asJson  /  toString
  Ok("Got: " + data)
}
```

I get respectively (for either `asJson` or toString)

```
Got: None   /  Got: AnyContentAsFormUrlEncoded(Map(jsonFile -> ArrayBuffer(file.json)))
```

The format of my `file.json` is:

```
[{ "name": "alice", "age": 22}, { "name": "bob", "age": 23}]
```

And I have already validated it as correctly formatted in JSON lint. Basically I can't seem to properly extract the content from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are not doing a request using a `Content-Type` of `application/json` and so you request body/payload is not the JSON. You are actually kind of doing a file uploading (it is not exactly a file upload because you are not using a `multipart/form-data`) using a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (you can confirm that by using the browser inspector).

Here is what you have to do:

1. Do a proper [file upload](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFileUpload) if you want users to submit the file using a web form
2. Read the file content and send it to Cassandra.

Comment: is there a way to read the content of the uploaded file without saving the file per se? I am not interested in storing the file anywhere I just want to extract the contents of the file as it is uploaded and then work on that content alone and discard the file object.

Comment: You can create your own body parser to do that: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Writing-a-custom-body-parser